# C++: gethostname() failing

Tags: c++, winapi, window, msdn, wsastartup

I need to get the system host name for which I am using [gethostname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx) function

But its failing with error code **10093** which is

> **WSANOTINITIALISED
>   10093**
>
> Successful WSAStartup not yet performed. Either the application has
>   not called WSAStartup or WSAStartup failed. The application may be
>   accessing a socket that the current active task does not own (that is,
>   trying to share a socket between tasks), or WSACleanup has been called
>   too many times.

Below is my program code:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>    
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{    
   char hostname[1024];
   hostname[1023] = '\0';
   gethostname(hostname, 1023);
   int err = WSAGetLastError();    
}
```

What might be causing this failure?

---

**EDIT**

Adding below code before gethostname function call solved the issue.

```
if (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData) != 0) 
{
  MessageBox (NULL, TEXT("WSAStartup failed!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `WSACleanup()` for every successful `WSAStartup()`. It is best to call `WSAStartup()` once at app start, then `WSACleanup()` at app exit.  But you can call `WSAStartup()` multiple times during the app's lifetime as long as you keep `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` balanced.

Comment: Here is the definition/declaration for the WSAData variable: WSADATA WSAData;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is written in the link you posted:

> A successful `WSAStartup` call must occur before using this function.

Call `WSAStartup`, check its return code, if all went well, call `gethostname`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. You need to call `WSAStartup` before `gethostname`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message: the application has not called `WSAStartup`